# Does Salsola grow better in standing water, or in a semi-dry environment?

Tags: watering

I'm trying to grow Salsola (land seaweed) this year, and was wondering if it's better to grow in a 5 gallon bucket full of water, or in a community garden plot that doesn't get watered more than about once per week.

Answer (score 1):

Probably neither is a good choice. S. soda grows in permanently humid, fertile coastal spots. Italian gardeners usually grow it during the humid winter months when it’s less likely to dry out. For areas with too cold winters, early spring sowing is recommend, too much summer heat can stress the plants and make the leaves tough.

If your community garden tends to fall dry occasionally, the Salsola won’t like it, so a container is the better choice, especially if you can pick a spot where it’s a bit protected. No need to drown it, though. You don’t need too much space unless you plan to cook a lot of it.

Note that the germination rate is notoriously low - sources vary between 40% and 60% - so sow generously. With only 60 days until harvest, it’s a good „in between“ crop and will probably regrow if cut carefully or if you harvest just the leaves.

Comment: I got a live plant. So how much dry land do I need before having soaking soil?

Comment: Use a pot with drainage holes, water regularly, empty saucer, if using. If you insist on using a container without holes, use your gardening knowledge and let at least dry out the top 1, maybe 2 inches. I recommend the first option.